# Store large amount of data to Database using Spring Batch

Tags: java, mysql, spring-batch, struts, batch-processing

- I'm having large amount of data to verify. Then setting in an object and
  finally save in database one by one. So it's consuming much time. I'm
  planning to use **Spring Batch** to store that large amount of data
  after processing in a single shot. By this I can eliminate the time
  taking to talk with db each time.
- Can I store the whole data in a list and store with **Spring batch**
  or there is any other way?
  Please help me with any example.
- Coading Language - **Java - struts**
- Database - **MySql Server**

Answer (score 0):

> Store large amount of data
>
> Can I store the whole data in a list

If your "large amount" of data fits in memory then you can do that. But I'm not sure this is the way to go if your data is big enough and would not fit in memory.

The idea of [chunk oriented processing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/step.html#chunkOrientedProcessing) in Spring Batch is to *not* load the whole data set in memory but to load it in chunks. This model is robust and can handle any amount of input data with a low memory footprint (only the chunk size items are loaded in memory).